# Utf8 Linux filenames and C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, utf-8, sdl-ttf

I am working at a OS independent file manager, using SDL_ttf to draw my text.
On Windows, everything works well, but on Linux I have to use the UTF8 functions of SDL_ttf, because the filenames can be UTF8 encoded.

This works well, but if I have my own C string (not a file name) such as "Ää", it will be displayed wrong. Is there any way to tell gcc to encode my strings as UTF8?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need anything special from your C compiler for UTF-8 string literals.  Proper support for it in the APIs you use is another matter, but that seems to be covered.

What you *do* need to do is to make sure your source files are actually saved in UTF-8, so that non-ASCII characters don't get converted to some other encoding when you edit or save the file.

The compiler doesn't need specific UTF-8 support, as long as it assumes 8-bit characters and the usual ASCII values for any syntactically significant characters; in other words, it's almost certainly not the problem.

Comment: This is right - it's likely your source code editor that's the problem (is it set to ISO-8859-1?).

Comment: Yeah, it is the source editor that is causing the issue. Although I used two (Textpad on Windows and some default text editor on Linux, and I was hoping the Linux one would convert it as UTF8 by default.)

Answer (score 1):

gcc should interpret your source code and string literals as UTF-8 by default. Try -fexec-charset

See also: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html#Implementation_002ddefined-behavior

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that the problem is that those characters ended up being in ASCII (1 octet) rather than UTF8. I tried the -fexec-charset option, but I got a: cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fexec-charset".

Answer (score 1):

C should have some sort of Unicode string literal syntax. Googling for "Unicode programming C" should get you started, two tutorials that seemed good are the one on [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linuni/index.html) and the one on [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html).

The general approach for your specific case would be using a wide string literal `L"Ää"`, then converting that into UTF-8 with `wcstrtombs()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never worked with wide strings before, could you please provide a small example on how to create a wide string with L"Ää"?

Comment: `L"whatever"` should already be a "wide string", that is, an array of wchar_t. (A wide string, however, isn't an UTF-8 string suitable for output.) If all you need is to output a literal somewhere that requires UTF-8, however, @teambob's answer should be sufficient. Wide strings are only necessary if you need to manipulate them in your code somehow.

Comment: Well, now that I looked at the .o file, it seems that the "Ää" string placed by gcc in there is an octet for each character, so no wonder that UTF8 routines can't display it properly. I got those characters by copying them from some web page, but I guess that if I write them from the keyboard under Linux, the proper UTF8 encoding would not be a problem.

Comment: Actually, copy/paste should work correctly, what's important is that both your text editor be set to save files as UTF-8, and your compiler be set to interpret them as UTF-8. If you're writing the code on Windows, I believe it's still reasonably common to save text files as Windows-1252 or whatever codepage is the default for your version of Windows.